# NASM assembly - why does call produce different result than jmp?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I am trying to determine why I get two different results when using call printMemory vs jmp printMemory.  It seems that they should produce the same result in this case as the call is returning to the same location as the jmp finish.

```
section .data
    a: dq 3.0
    b: dq 4.0
    c: dq 0.0
    result: dq 0.0
    printMsg: db "a(%f)^2 + b(%f)^2 = c^2 (%f)",10,0
    printMsg2: db "c = %f",10,0
    printMsg3: db "%f",10,0

section .text
    extern printf
    extern sqrt
    global main


main:
    push rbp    
    mov rbp, rsp
    finit
    fld qword [a]
    fmul qword [a]
    fstp qword [result]
    fld qword [b]
    fmul qword [b]
    fadd qword [result]
    fstp qword [result]
    mov rdi, printMsg
    movq xmm0, qword [a]
    movq xmm1, qword [b]
    movq xmm2, qword [result]
    mov rax, 3
    call printf
    movq xmm0, qword [result]
    call sqrt
    mov rdi, printMsg2
    mov rax, 1
    call printf
    call printMemory
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall 


printMemory:
    mov rdi, printMsg3
    movq xmm0, qword [a]
    mov rax, 1
    call printf
    ret
```

This causes a segmentation fault

But this outputs the expected result:

```
section .data
    a: dq 3.0
    b: dq 4.0
    c: dq 0.0
    result: dq 0.0
    printMsg: db "a(%f)^2 + b(%f)^2 = c^2 (%f)",10,0
    printMsg2: db "c = %f",10,0
    printMsg3: db "%f",10,0

section .text
    extern printf
    extern sqrt
    global main


main:
    push rbp    
    mov rbp, rsp
    finit
    fld qword [a]
    fmul qword [a]
    fstp qword [result]
    fld qword [b]
    fmul qword [b]
    fadd qword [result]
    fstp qword [result]
    mov rdi, printMsg
    movq xmm0, qword [a]
    movq xmm1, qword [b]
    movq xmm2, qword [result]
    mov rax, 3
    call printf
    movq xmm0, qword [result]
    call sqrt
    mov rdi, printMsg2
    mov rax, 1
    call printf
    jmp printMemory
finish:
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    mov rax, 60
    xor rdi, rdi
    syscall 


printMemory:
    mov rdi, printMsg3
    movq xmm0, qword [a]
    mov rax, 1
    call printf
    jmp finish
```

Comment: which line causes the segmentation fault?

Comment: The call printf in printMemory

Comment: I suspect what is going on is that your printMemory function doesn't properly align the stack on a 16-byte boundary. This is required by the x86-64 System V ABI You can push a register at the beginning of printMemory and restore it before the ret. Pushing the additional 8 bytes will align the stack in the function printMemory.